# Failed to execute 'appendChild' on 'Node' error thrown when attempting to append a child in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to append a block of code using jQuery, and end up with the following error:

`Failed to execute 'appendChild' on 'Node': parameter 1 is not of type 'Node'.`

My code is as follows:

```
<script id=social language="text">
  <a href="https://www.facebook.com/" target="_blank">
    <i class="fa fa-lg fa-facebook-f"></i>
  </a>
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
   $('.social').append(document.getElementById('social'));
</script>

<div class="col-sm-7 social"></div>
```

Comment: Your code is not correct, you can't place HTML code into `<script></script>` tags.

Answer (score 1):

You can't place HTML within a `<script>` tag.

Try something like this:

```
<div id=social>
  <a href="https://www.facebook.com/" target="_blank">
    <i class="fa fa-lg fa-facebook-f"></i>
  </a>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
   $('.social').append(document.getElementById('social'));
</script>

<div class="col-sm-7 social">facebook</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't really do it the way how you're doing it.  I would recommend this way.  You can do multi-line quotes by using the ` character (lowercase tilda on the keyboard).  I did that.  Additionally, you should always put your JavaScript at the bottom of the page (or body).

```
<div class="col-sm-7 social"></div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
social = `<a href="https://www.facebook.com/" target="_blank">
    <i class="fa fa-lg fa-facebook-f"></i>test string
  </a>`;


$('.social').append(social);
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

@vsoni,
Is your first block an error in your code or just a copy error?
This block:

```
<script id=social language="text">
  <a href="https://www.facebook.com/" target="_blank">
    <i class="fa fa-lg fa-facebook-f"></i>
  </a>
</script>
```

Should be something like:

```
<p id="social" language="text">
  <a href="https://www.facebook.com/" target="_blank">
    <i class="fa fa-lg fa-facebook-f"></i>
  </a>
</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(function() {
    $('.social').append( document.getElementById('social').innerHTML );
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-wvfXpqpZZVQGK6TAh5PVlGOfQNHSoD2xbE+QkPxCAFlNEevoEH3Sl0sibVcOQVnN" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div id="social" style="display:none;">
  <a href="https://www.facebook.com/" target="_blank">
    <i class="fa fa-lg fa-facebook-f"></i>
  </a>
</div>


<div class="col-sm-7 social">facebook</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have tried to put my code block in javascript as I wanted to hide it in front end. But now I manage it thorough css.

```js
$( document ).ready(function(){
   $('.social').append(document.getElementById('social'));
   $('#social').css('display','block');
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-sm-7 social"></div>

<p id="social" style="display: none">
  <a href="https://www.facebook.com/" target="_blank">
    inserting something
  </a>
</p>
```

Thanks everyone for taking time to look at this. you guys are awesome.